# Google Calender Notfiy When on Event Creation

Tags: php, calendar

How can I receive event info when it is created on google calender site ..
I want to get the event and process it using my script ..

example :

1- user create an event in Google Calender site
2- Google push the event to my url www.example.com/event.php
3-event.php will process the event data

the question how can configure Calender to send the  creation event? is this applicable or should i use cron job to query Google calander and fetch events

Answer (score 0):

Google introduced push notifications for calendar,
for more details refer http://googledevelopers.blogspot.ch/2013/07/google-calendar-api-push-notifications.html